# How to change Native Mode to SharePoint Integrated Mode in SQL Server 2012

Tags: 2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server 2012 in Native Mode. How can I change it to SharePoint Integrated Mode? In the Reporting Service Configuration Manager Tool I found that there is no option to change Native to SharePoint mode.

Can I do this using any PowerShell command or Central Administration? Please advice as I do not want to reinstall the SQL Server instance as it might severely affect our client data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So by Native-mode vs. Integrated Mode you are actually refering to Reporting Services.

I assume you also know that one major implication/difference between the 2 modes is the fact that by example, the reports definition files and Data Sources are stored in the SharePoint Content database. Also, there is no concept of “Report Manager” in SharePoint Integrated mode since it is deployed to the SharePoint Reports Library. Security trimming for reports is handled using standard SharePoint permissions.

In SharePoint Integrated mode, when a user makes a request for a particular report, the Report Server Proxy Endpoint will take care of the report processing from SharePoint along with Report Services to return the rendered result.

Read more if interested here http://www.optimusbi.com/2012/11/23/ssrs-integrated-vs-native-mode/

So to conclude, to my knowledge there is no such thing as easy command, in neither technologies (SSRS nor SharePoint) - and that is mainly due to implications such as those mentioned above.

You would need to consider backup of databases, unistalling and re-installing (or if you can afford create anothe installation, on another SQL server and repoint to it after restore) the SSRS extensions and deploying all reports currently stored in SharePoint, back to the database - AT LEAST!

Comment: This is correct. The SSRS SharePoint Integrated mode is now a separate installation option during SQL Server setup (and must be done on a SharePoint server joined to the farm). So the process would be, export the encryption key, remove the SSRS service, re-install SSRS in SharePoint mode, install the SSRS service instance, create a new SSRS Service Application using the same SSRS databases as before, then import the encryption key into the SSRS SA that you just created.

Comment: We have got a SharePoint 2013, SQL installation on MACHINE 1. On MACHINE 2 we have got the TFS, SQL and reporting installed. Now how do we configure the SHarePoint integrated mode on MACHINE 2?

Answer (score 0):

I found this but haven't tried it yet, if I can get it to work I will post more info!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jameswu/archive/2012/04/21/reporting-services-migration-tool.aspx